# How to create a new dataframe by using values of another

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have 2 **pandas dataframe**s (one mapping currencies for symbols over time and the other mapping values for currencies over time) how can I **get to value per symbol over time**?

```
sym = pd.DataFrame(data=[["USD","EUR"],["USD","CAD"]],columns=["FB", "SAP"])
```

and

```
fx = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns = ["USD","EUR","CAD"])
```

to get

```
adj = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2], [4, 6]], columns = ["FB", "SAP"])?
```

Answer (score 2):

`stack` + `lookup`

```
dd=sym.stack().to_frame('value')
dd.loc[:,'value']=fx.lookup(dd.index.get_level_values(0),dd['value'])
dd
Out[973]: 
       value
0 FB       1
  SAP      2
1 FB       4
  SAP      6
dd.unstack()
Out[974]: 
  value    
     FB SAP
0     1   2
1     4   6
```